# How to return formatted(pretty) JSON instead of JSON? Or new line JSON instead of inline JSON?(Laravel)

Tags: json, laravel

While returning data from laravel routes or controllers, they are automatically returned as JSON data. That's cool but reading these data into the web page it's difficult. Because they're inline, and it's hard to identify elements. I know I could use something like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#. To format the json data to be readable. But I was wondering if this could be done into the laravel web route or controller?

The route below is part of web.php file. Also `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`.

```
Route::get('usersAsJson', function(){
   return DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get();
});
```

This returns inline JSON, something like this:

> [{"id":1,"name":"Winifred
> Glover","email":"wkeebler@example.net","email_verified_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi","remember_token":"aUEs6ZqylC","created_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","updated_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29"},{"id":2,"name":"Bernadine
> Carter","email":"michelle.terry@example.com","email_verified_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi","remember_token":"RpXyMl9N8i","created_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","updated_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29"},{"id":3,"name":"Roberta
> Brakus","email":"halle.heathcote@example.org","email_verified_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi","remember_token":"SfEj3TUqbY","created_at":"2021-12-15
> 13:22:29","updated_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29"}]

and I would like new line JSON something like:

```
[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"Winifred Glover",
     "email":"wkeebler@example.net",
     "email_verified_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC\/.og\/at2.uheWG\/igi",
     "remember_token":"aUEs6ZqylC",
     "created_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "updated_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "name":"Bernadine Carter",
     "email":"michelle.terry@example.com",
     "email_verified_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC\/.og\/at2.uheWG\/igi",
     "remember_token":"RpXyMl9N8i",
     "created_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "updated_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29"
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "name":"Roberta Brakus",
     "email":"halle.heathcote@example.org",
     "email_verified_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "password":"$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC\/.og\/at2.uheWG\/igi",
     "remember_token":"SfEj3TUqbY",
     "created_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29",
     "updated_at":"2021-12-15 13:22:29"
  }
]
```

Comment: You need a chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en - Laravel returns this as text/json, its correct, its just your browser rendering it.

Comment: As an alternative, wrapping your call in `dd()`, like `dd(DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get());` will display nicely formatted, but not as JSON. Kinda depends on what you're trying to do accomplish with this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `response()->json()` method to generate your json response, you can pass in the encoding options in the fourth parameter.

```
Route::get('usersAsJson', function(){
   return response()->json(DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get(), 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
});
```

---

If you plan on doing this in a lot of places, I would suggest defining a new [response macro](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#response-macros) (e.g. `prettyJson()`) and using that to clean up the code a little bit.

Add this to your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::macro('prettyJson', function ($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0) {
    return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($data, $status, $headers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | $options);
});
```

Then you can use the new `prettyJson` method on your response, and it'll take care of adding in the pretty print option for you (and still retain all the other functionality of the original `json()` method):

```
Route::get('usersAsJson', function(){
   return response()->prettyJson(DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get());
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using to consult the endpoint if postmant, firefox or google chrome and most importantly if the header has the `Content-Type` type in `application/json`
I tend to use
`response()->json(DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get());`
In postman [image]

In Firefox[image]

This no work in Google Chrome (in my devices).

Comment: Yes I know you can choose pretty JSON with Postman. Also using some extension on Chrome, and maybe in some other browsers. Or even using some online formatter. But I was wondering if you could do this with laravel. So that way you don't have to worry switching between browsers(if it has installed pretty JSON extension or not). The idea is the respond from the server to be formatted as pretty JSON before leaving server. And not doing this on the client side. I'm not sure if methods like 'trim spaces' are used before catching this data from response but I was just wondering.

Comment: You could use the `dump()` helper to visualize it on the server side before throwing it, I tend to use it with `dump-server` so as not to cut the application flow and see what it shows

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-pretty-print

`return json_decode(DB::table('users')->limit(3)->get(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`